# Django: Filtering query to a specific id

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I have a podcast management website where a user is able to setup his account and after that will be able to create multiple episode from that specific user. After an episode is done, a button will appear where he can see some links that is created automatically for the user to use. The problem I am having is that for every episode, I am trying to show the links for that specific one but it always keeps showing the links from the one I recently created and other episodes that were previously created.

This is the button where the user click when the episode has created the links:

```
<a class="btn btn-info box-shadow--6dp" href="{% url 'pf:episodereview' production_id=instance.id %}" role="button"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp Review Links</a>
```

The URL pattern in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^episodereview/(?P<production_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.EpisodeReview.as_view(), name="episodereview"),
```

This is what happens in `views.py`:

```
class EpisodeReview(LoginRequiredMixin, ProductionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'pf/forms_episode_review.html'
    podcast = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        production_id = kwargs.get('production_id', None)

        if production_id:
            production = Production.objects.filter(id=production_id).first()
            if not production:
                return self.handle_no_permission()

        return super(EpisodeReview, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Production.objects.filter(podcast=self.podcast)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('pf:dashboard')
```

And the template where everything is displayed:

```
{% extends "pf/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block content %}

<br>
<br>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

<h3><i class="fa fa-wpforms pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>Episode Review&nbsp</h3>

<h5>Following links are generated automatically with your accounts and can be used immediately.</h5>

<hr/>

    {% if object_list %}

        <table class='table'>
            <tbody>
            {% for instance in object_list %}
                <ul>
                    <li><b>Wordpress URL:</b> {{ instance.wordpress_url }}</li>
                    <li><b>Wordpress Short URL:</b> {{ instance.wordpress_short_url }}</li>
                    <li><b>Soundcloud Result URL:</b>{{ instance.soundcloud_result_url }}</li>
                    <li><b>Youtube Result URL:</b>{{ instance.youtube_result_url }}</li>
                    <li><b>Libsyn Result URL:</b>{{ instance.libsyn_result_url }}</li>
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {% endif %}
<hr/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info box-shadow--6dp"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbspSave
</button>

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Welcome any suggestion!

Comment: Try to put `print(production_id)` just above the if function and see if it gets the correct `production_id`.

Comment: @1GDST Yeah, it gets the right `id`

Answer (score 0):

You filter by the id in the get method, but then don't do anything with the result. When it comes to construct the template context, Django calls get_queryset, which only filters by self.podcast - which is None.

You should move that filter logic into get_queryset. And if you also want to filter by podcast, you should find a way to define that parameter too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just to understand, should I remove the `get` method and leave the `get_queryset` with all the filter logic? The links are in each individual `production` **(which is considered an episode)** and `production` is in `podcast` so I just want to filter all 5 URLs in that `production` that were created for that specific `production`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My main question was the first sentence. The rest is just a more in depth description of how is the user flow.

Comment: Got it working btw, had to use `get_object` instead of `get_queryset`. Thanks for the help though!